# Knex query error undefined column using nested select with orderBy

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

In a Knex query I'm getting that a column is undefined and I don't know how to resolve

the query I have in Knex

```
this.builder.orderBy(
    this.tx(messageTable)
      .max(messageColumns.createdAt)
      .where(messageColumns.conversationId, 'conversation.id')
, direction)
```

The undefined happen on the last part of the `.where(messageColumns.conversationId, 'conversation.id')`

the SQL I want to get it to work with Knex is as follow

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "conversation"
ORDER BY
    (
        SELECT
            max("created_at")
        FROM
            "message"
        WHERE
            "conversation_id" = conversation.id)
    DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is wrong , try to do this:

```
select c.* from conversation c
join (
    select conversation_id, max("created_at") created_at
    from message
    group by conversation_id
) m on c.conversation_id = m.conversation_id
order by m.created_at DESC
```

Comment: That interesting but I need an example in KnexJs

Comment: By the way that query gives the following error
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "conversation"
LINE 12:    conversation_id) m ON c.conversation.id = m.conversation_...

Comment: @Jakub ,are you sure, the query looks ok to me .

Comment: So I had to do a new one but I have a new issue can you give me your opinion here please https://stackoverflow.com/q/67003367/7882685