# Knex query syntax error near SELECT in the join method

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to build a join with Knex of 2 tables. The query I did gave me back a syntax error

`syntax error at or near \"select\"`

The query I built

```
this.builder
      .join(
        this.tx(messageTable)
          .select(messageColumns.conversationId)
          .max(messageColumns.createdAt, 'updated_at')
          .where(messageColumns.conversationId, columns.id)
          .groupBy(messageColumns.conversationId),
        messageColumns.conversationId,
        'updated_at'
      )
```

And the SQL generated which also gives same syntax error in the SELECT after the join

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "conversation"
    INNER JOIN
    SELECT
        "conversation_id",
        max("created_at")
    FROM
        "message"
    WHERE
        "conversation_id" = 'id'
    GROUP BY
        "conversation_id" ON "conversation_id" = "updated_at"
```

What should be the right way to do it in knex to avoid the syntax error

Answer (score 1):

I decided to answer my own question as maybe someone could have similar issue in the future.

The error was given by the fact KnexJS was generated an SQL on the `INNER JOIN` without parenthesis `(...)` so the right SQL should look as follow

`INNER JOIN ( SELECT ... )`

The right Knex then was as follow to use

```js
this.builder
      .join(
        function innerSelect() {
          this.select(messageColumns.conversationId)
            .from(messageTable)
            .max(`${messageTable}.${messageColumns.createdAt} as updated_at`)
            .groupBy(messageColumns.conversationId)
            .as('m');
        },
        messageColumns.conversationId,
        'id'
      )
```

The reason is to let understand the Knex a subquery in the correct way you need to add a `function` and similar is showed in the docs http://knexjs.org/#Builder-join